# Setting Up Concourse with external url

Tags: docker-compose, concourse, concourse-fly

Currently following the Concourse Tutorial (https://concoursetutorial.com/), but I am stuck at the Deploy Concourse using Docker Compose step. As indicated in the docs, "You need to set the external url env variable inside the docker-compose.yml"

```
- CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL
+ CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL=http://{{my-server}}:8080
```

**What I tried:**
replacing {{my-server}} with localhost but putting http://localhost:8080 in my browser does not work; site cannot be reached error.

What do I replace **{{my-server}}** with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [docker-compose](https://concourse-ci.org/docker-compose.yml) on https://concourse-ci.org. The `environment` section has a slightly different format. I'm not sure if S&W tutorial uses some legacy format or if it's simply broken, but you can take my word that the one on concourse-ci.org will work without any modification.

So give https://concourse-ci.org/quick-start.html a try (it's also a docker-compose-based instance).

Comment: Using the suggested docker-compose based instance, I was able to correctly download and view on my localhost. Thank you!